# Como deixa um TableLayout em um tamanho fixo na tela?

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma tela onde tem um título, uma tabela e dois botões em baixo da tabela. Eu coloquei a tabela dentro de um scrollView. Porém, quando a tabela vai enchendo de linhas, ela vai ocupado o lugar dos botões até desaparecer. Alguém sabe como resolver isso? Agradeço desde já. Segue um exemplo da minha estrutura:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: dê um `android:id` para o `LinearLayout` onde tem os dois botões. No seu `<ScrollView>`, adicone: `android:above:+id/idQueVoceAtribuiuAoLayoutDosBotoes`

Comment: @MarllonNasser `above` é um atributo do *RelativeLayout* o que está a ser utilizado é um *LinearLayout*

Comment: E por que não usar `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: eu coloquei o id em todos, só tirei para mostrar aqui para ficar mais limpo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente adicionar android:layout_weight="1" no seu ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso. Obrigadão.